# Visual Studio 2010 IDE question

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I double click an item in the find window, the C/CPP file opens in a tab next to the find window. I want it open in the main window (center) along with the other c/cpp files. Is there a setting to get this behaviour ? Thanks

Comment: For eg. when you do a "find in files", the matches are displayed in a window in the lower pane of he IDE (the pane which is mostly used to display build status, breakpoints etc). When I now double click an item in the find list the source file that opens will show up in the lower pane of the IDE rather than the center pane which typically is used for the source files.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that setting has been modified somewhere. I've tried to reproduce the behaviour in a new(ish) installation of Visual Studio 2010, and can't reproduce. Perhaps you've chosen the C++ Development Settings where the behavior is different from the C# Dev Settings.

Consider resetting your Visual Studio 2010 settings.

> Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset All Settings